# Javascript JSON.parse: unexpected character error

Tags: php, javascript, json

I want to get a string from a php script, and parse it to a javascript array. but got the error : **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character** for the line :JSON.parse(msg);

I searched a lot , couldn't figure out where is my problem, please help check for me. Thanks.

PHP side :

```
header("application/json; charset=utf-8");
$sum = array(1,2,3,4,5);
echo json_encode($sum);
```

Javascript :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "save.php",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: price,
    success: function (msg) {
        var i = 0;
        console.log(msg);
        var sum = new Array();
        sum = JSON.parse(msg);
        $('input.hj').each(function () {
            if (sum[i] > 0) {
                $(this).val(sum[i]);
            }
            i++;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Just have a look at the output of `console.log(msg);`. Is it an object or a string? If it is an object, you don't have to and cannot parse it.

Comment: @FelixKling it is a string like this : [1,2,3,4,5] I want to parse this to be an Array

Comment: Does `console.log(typeof msg);` show `string` as well?

Comment: @FelixKling  if I put header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8"); in php, the success function doesn't work. If I remove that header, the msg type is string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't parse it : `$.ajax` parsed it for you. Just use the argument which is given to your `success` callback, this is the parsed array.

If your browser can't detect it's JSON, add the `dataType` argument.

Note also that you don't have to manage the `i` counter yourself : one is passed by `each` :

```
dataType: 'json',
success: function(sum){
    $('input.hj').each(function(i){
        if (sum[i] > 0) {
            $(this).val(sum[i]);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: without parsing, I got the value as a String like this "[1,2,3,4,5]" it output "[" "1"  ","  .....  It's not what I want. Thanks

Comment: Did you also fix the bad header in PHP noticed by Marcelo ? It looks like your browser can't detect it's JSON.

Comment: To be sure, set also the dataType argument.

Comment: I fixed the header like this header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");  then the success function doesn't work anymore, no console output.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to parse it. Also, in your **PHP** script, your `header` should be:

```
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

In your **JS**, if `price` is a string (or float or int), there is no need to send it as json. For simplification, you may want to remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`,

Comment: It's not redundant. The `contentType` option specifies the format of the data **sent** to the sever. Of course if `price` is not JSON, then the header is wrong, but that's a different reason.

Comment: @FelixKling You're right, it's not redundant if it sends a JSON. Which is not the case. I'll edit.